# Find paypal api credential

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I already build a paypal account and then 
I created Sandbox Test Accounts in "https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/", 
1 personal account and 
1 business account.

now I want to use below credential where can I find these.

```
PAYPAL_USERNAME
PAYPAL_PASSWORD
PAYPAL_SIGNATURE
PAYPAL_MERCHANT_ID

PAYPAL_BUSINESS
PAYPAL_CERT_ID
```

please help me out, I am new in paypal api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal is having pretty good documentation.
To create API Username, API Password, Signature follow the steps

1. Select **Profile** on the right side of page -- Select **Profile and settings**
2. From left menu, select **My selling tools**
3. In selling online section, click **Update link for API access** item
4. Click on **Request API Credentials** on the API Access page
5. Select **Request API signature** and click **Agree and Submit** to generate the API signature

more details [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/apiCredentials/)

Answer (score 1):

The only things you should need are a client id and secret. This will enable you to make REST api calls. If you're new to PayPal APIs, the REST api is where you should be starting.

Please see https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/